Sliding door effect, move elements with horizontal scroll by css instead of intersection observer
I'm trying to move riv1 in one direction on scroll, for example left and riv2 in the opposite position on scroll to reveal the background but the code still doesn't work. I'm trying css like a different approach to intersection observer.


.riviste-background {
  background: url('../img/vincitrice.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 50% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  height: calc(150vh - 15vw);
}

.riviste-background>img {
  animation-timeline: view(auto);
  animation-duration: 800ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.riviste {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin-inline: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

#riv1 {
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: slide-right linear;
}

#riv2 {
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: slide-left linear;
}

@keyframes slide-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-75%)
  }
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(75%)
  }
}
<div class="row riviste-background">

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/400" alt="" class="riviste" id="riv1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/400" alt="" class="riviste" id="riv2">`
</div>




You are overwriting the animation duration etc. by using animation on the two ids. Use animation-name etc instead.

If you aren't going to trigger the animation when the element comes into the viewport, what action is going to trigger it?

I want that triggers when elemets come into the viewport. Per one Id the image must go to left and for the other must go to right, like the supermarket doors. Every piece must go in different direction

So why 'different approach to intersectionObserver' which would seem to be the sensible thing to use here.

I mean that I want to try to not use javascript but css. But animation doesn't works here and I don't know why

Hmm, the only CSS thing I know about that senses entry to the viewport is view() see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timeline/view It is not supported on some common browsers (e.g. FF and Safari) and relies on scrolling to continue the animation so probably not what you want.
